# hide the progressbar after loading webview in android

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

i want to know what is the problem when i add this piece of code to my code.

```
  web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
       web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
   }});
```

`Progressbar` & `textview` never become invisible after `webview` loading is finished

```
public class YazdMap extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;
TextView txt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yazd_map);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);



    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://google.com/");



   web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
       web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
 }
});


}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        txt.setVisibility(view.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;

    }


}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack())
    {web.goBack();
    return true;}

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: remove this whole code `web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {` and move `onReceivedError` inside `myWebClient extends WebViewClient`

Comment: please explian more

Comment: you can ask your doubts , otherwise i will have to post an answer for explanation and e.g

Comment: i dont know where i must put this code in my codes @PavneetSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) `web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {` will override the previous set webview `new myWebClient()`, so remove this

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
       web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
 }
});
```

2.) Move your `onReceivedError` inside `myWebClient` class so code will be

```
public class YazdMap extends ActionBarActivity {

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView txt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_yazd_map);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://google.com/");

    }

    public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                txt.setVisibility(view.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
               view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack())
        {web.goBack();
        return true;}

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Note : i changed the name from `myWebClient` to `MyWebClient` because class must have first letter as an upper case according to convention.